# How to interrupt thread for console reading?

Tags: java, input, concurrency, console

I have such problem: program should read information from console in separate thread, and when l want to close this thread - input remains active. How to close input after interrupting thread? (programm runs at Eclipse IDE)

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       ChatRunner.reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in, ChatRunner.charset));

        //some treatment

        final Thread input = new Thread(() -> {

            try {
                ChatRunner.answerFromConsole = ChatRunner.reader.readLine();
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                //
            }

        });

        input.start();
        // some treatment


        input.interrupt();
    }
}
```

If l simply close BufferedReader, i can't use it in next step in loop.

Comment: Close `System.in`.